# Autodesk Forge Getting layers from sketchup model

Tags: autodesk-forge, sketchup

I'm using the forge viewer and would like to associate each mesh with it's layer (if it has one). For most formats I'm able to find the layer information by looking at the properties returned from viewer.model.getProperties(dbId, ...). Unfortunately Sketchup models don't seem to have this information. Is there another way I can find the layer data for Sketchup files?

Comment: Hi @user3179594, getProperties reflects what you can see from property panel of UI. It looks only limited properties are available with a *.skp file object. While in Navisworks, the [layer] property is extracted. I am checking with corresponding engineer team (Sketchup extractor of Forge) to have their comments.

Comment: Hi @user3179594,  our engineer team told me there is a plan more properties of *.skp will be extracted in the future release soon. However we cannot guarantee until it is available in the final release. I will update this post when the property is supported. Thank you for your patience! At this moment, probably you could use Navisworks to import and send *.nwd to Forge translation.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang Okay thanks for letting me know. I will integrate Skp layers into my app when the feature becomes available.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang I am now seeing layer information returned for skp files when I call viewer.model.getProperties(dbId, ...). It looks like it was integrated! Thank you!

Comment: yes, I also just got to know 'layer with skp' is released to the production a few days ago :) Please let us know any further questions!